# Spring Framework is not updating child entity when parent is updated

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I can not figure out what is wrong. Here is my Hotel entity which has Restaurants:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hotel"})
private List<Restaurant> restaurants;
```

And here is my Restaurant entity which has Hotels:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "restaurant_hotel",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id")
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"restaurants"})
private Hotel hotel;
```

When I update a restaurant I can set the hotel without a problem and see the change when I look at the hotel. But when I update a hotel, only the hotel gets updated. The hotel's restaurants do not get updated.

Just to clarify that I have no intention to alter the restaurant entity itself while updating the hotel and vice versa. Just want to change which restaurants belong to the hotel while updating the hotel entity. Right now I can only change the hotel when updating the restaurant.

I checked the hotel object before it is saved with `org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository` and it has the correct restaurants with it.

Comment: Cascading into both directions is bad practice. There are other discussions that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534599/a-question-on-jpa-cascading

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ and in particular the section 
in the Bidirectional @OneToMany that mentions the two utility methods on the parent entity.

> The parent entity, Post, features two utility methods (e.g. addComment and removeComment) which are used to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association. You should always provide these methods whenever you are working with a bidirectional association as, otherwise, you risk very subtle state propagation issues.

I believe your issue relates to similar state propagation issues and it will be resolved if you add the utility methods addRestaurant, removeRestaurant in the parent Hotel entity and use them before updating the Hotel.

```
    public void addRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        restaurants.add(restaurant);
        restaurant.setHotel(this);
    }

    public void removeRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        restaurants.remove(restaurant);
        restaurant.setHotel(null);
    }
```

The difference between your case and the one in the link is that you're using @JoinTable instead of @JoinColumn but I don't think that matters anyway.